# build failed with "taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found"

Tags: android, cordova, build-process

i am following the instructions here: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/ch07_id35817064.html in order to build a native android app from a HTML project using Phonegap on my Mac with Mountain Lion.

The build fails with these error messages:

```
Building phonegap.jar

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/phonegap-android-master/src/build.xml:49: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found
```

After some internet investigation i tried to set up the sdk.dir which did not work either:

```
MacintoshEwald-3:bin private$ /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk
-bash: /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk: is a directory
MacintoshEwald-3:bin private$ sdk.dir=/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk
-bash: sdk.dir=/Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk: No such file or directory
```

I can find numerous postings with the same problem on the internet, but no answers to it. Can someone help me to fix my problem?

Thank you

Ewald

Comment: You could see the answer in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15719072/2114308

Answer (score 0):

I am getting similar problem on windows. After investigating I found out that the anttasks.jar file in android-sdk/tools/lib doesn't have com.android.ant.SetupTask class. I don't know if this file is broken or what. I have android platform 8 and 17.