# taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Tags: android

I'm trying to get some simple Android apps working from the book 'Beginning Android 4'.  I ran ant on one of the source code directories and received this error:

```
# ant debug
Buildfile: NowRedux/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
NowRedux/build.xml:49: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

The lines in build.xml which is causing this are:

```
<taskdef name="setup"
    classname="com.android.ant.SetupTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?  I tried downloading ant at http://ant.apache.org/ and manually installing it, but that did not help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if this was the correct way to solve the problem, or it merely sidesteps it, but I did this

```
rm MyProjects/NowRedux/build.xml
android update project --target 8 --path MyProjects/NowRedux
```

And it worked.  It basically creates a new build.xml file that doesn't refer to com.android.ant.SetupTask (so, that problem might still be broken, but at least I found a workaround)

Comment: Please note that `--target 8` is not a real SDK version, rather subject to the number of installed SDKs of a given machine. Meaning, if you want to align with android sdk 18 for example, it'll be `--target 8` on one machine, but `--target 5` on another (check out to output of `android list targets` and it'll all make sense).