# com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found

Tags: java, android, ant

I would need to build one android app from command line. I successfully compiled its jni part, but cannot build Java part. `ant` prints the following (paths have been removed):

```
/.../build.xml:69: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found
    using the classloader AntClassLoader[/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/manifest-merger.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/common.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/guava-13.0.1.ja    r:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/sdklib.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/layoutlib-api.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/dvlib.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.4    8.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/commons-compress-1.0.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/httpmime-4.1.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar:/path    /to/sdk/tools/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/path/to/sdk/tools/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar]
```

It seems that SetupTask is inside `anttasks.jar`, but it is not in my `sdk` directory. I tried to install all available sdks, tried to add `ant-tasks.jar` to the class path (it has similar name), but with no success. Is there any way how to install `anttasks.jar`, or is it replaced by something else?  Or is `SetupTask` obsolete in some way?

I have run:

```
android update project ...
```

I tried to find answer by google but with no success for this particular issue (`AntClassLoader` is not empty, `anttasks.jar` is missing).

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this issue also.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik the SetupTask ist obsolete in Android 2.3 and higher. So it seems to me like you're working with an old version of the build.xml. Since Android 2.3 and higher, there is a new template for the build.xml in the directory
 your-android-SDK/tools/ant/. You can modify this one according to your needs.

Maybe this link will help you, it pointed me in the right direction:

https://sites.google.com/site/sokolkosta/internal-blog/includingadditionaljavaxpackagesinandroid23

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719072/1343309
It worked for me.

```
rm MyProjects/NowRedux/build.xml
android update project --target 8 --path MyProjects/NowRedux
```